# Display custom app storage information in iOS Settings

Tags: ios, storage, settings

I have an app that downloads large files. I noticed a while ago that when you download a movie in Netflix and then go into `Settings>General>iPhone Storage` and tap on Netflix it will display the downloaded content underneath the standard app storage header.

I have searched everywhere on how to get that set up but can't find any mention of it. Settings bundles don't seem to be the correct answer.

Does anyone know how to tie into that? Is it a feature for media? Some key set on the file?

Here is what I mean, note the downloaded video's section:
[image: Iphone Storage screen]

Answer (score 1):

When creating the `AVAssetDownloadTask` you use, presumably, one of the following methods:

1. `makeAssetDownloadTask`/`assetDownloadTaskWithURLAsset` (Swift/Objective-C)
2. `aggregateAssetDownloadTask`/`aggregateAssetDownloadTaskWithURLAsset` (Swift/Objective-C)

There you have as one of the parameters a `assetArtworkData`, for which the documentation states the following:

> Optional artwork data for this asset. This value will be displayed in the usage pane of the Settings app.

That is the parameter you need to provide data to in order for the thumbnail to be visible.